# Can I convert a double rocker combination switch to a single switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, outdoor

I have a double rocker switch controlling two sections of LED potlights on the outside of our home. I'd like to convert them to a single switch because I can't find a programmable double rocker switch so I can put the lights on a timer.

Is that possible? Current switch has 2 load wires and one hot.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could tie the loads together, add a pigtail and and connect the pigtail to a single switch.

Answer (score 1):

Since both switched hots from your double rocker are sourced from the same hot connection, then yes, absolutely you can replace with a single switch. Unless the new switch for some reason has terminals for accepting multiple wires, then you will need a pigtail. Obviously the downside is that you can't control each part independently anymore, but I'm guessing you are not especially concerned about that.

Don't use a "backstab connector" especially to avoid a pigtail. UL does not test for multiple connections on switches. They do technically test this on receptacles, including the screw and backstab combination, but so many electricians have horror stories about the use of backstab terminals that they are probably best avoided.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info, it was exactly what I hoped for!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative that wouldn't affect the switches or bulbs would be the Smart Light Socket type of product.  These run as cheap as $10 each.

[Example Hubspace Socket](https://www.homedepot.com/p/316692074)

If the smart socket or smart bulb idea doesn't fit your project, then a single timer switch would work too.

[Example Timer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/300524126) - This is probably similar to what you found already.  They don't make duplex LED timers.

Comment: A link to the Smart Light socket and single timer switch would be helpful so as to present them to everyone.

Comment: @RMDman Links added.

Comment: perfect. thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! I'll look into these options.